# Windows 8 add attachments via code

Tags: c#, windows-8

I had a problem in adding attachments using `emailcomposetask` in `wp7` as it didn't support it. Have they `fixed this in windows 8`? If yes, then how can I add attachment `via the code` in windows 8 store app?

From what I have learned from [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-metro-app-sending), I guess we can't do it. But I want to be sure, has anyone achieved it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't attach file to a mail via code in a Windows Store app. You need to use Sharing for this task, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx.

Comment: but will it open the email compose window? as i have to, from and other email related details and want to send an email only and do nothing else i.e. I don't want the user to chose any other option other than email. Will it work in that situation?

Comment: No, you can't choose the app to which you are able to share data.